# How to train time series model with multiple time series of slightly varying lengths?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series

I read this [Train LSTM model with multiple time series](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45600/train-lstm-model-with-multiple-time-series) post and acted on the answer by using the TimeSeriesGenerator function to make a window and used stride/batch lengths so each run was split up. However, because each of my time series are different lengths (between 7 and 13 hours), what would be the best way to train a model on each of these different objects?
In a regression model I would just split by index of the run but for the time series models it seems more challenging as the default is to split by fixed lengths and using sliding windows.